# AngularJS : binding doesn't work when a method of a controller is called from a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding

In the following code, when I click on the `span`, the new `movesNumber` value is updated on the view but when the method `newMove()` is called from the directive, the value of `movesNumber` in the `gameCtrl` scope is incremented but isn't updated in the view.

I guess there is something specific with the binding when the scope of a controller is called from a directive but I don't see how.

Here is my HTML :

```
<section ng-controller="gameCtrl" ng-show="gameIsVisible">

  <span ng-click="newMove()">{{ movesNumber }} / {{ maxRightMovesNumber }}</span>

  <block ng-repeat="block in game[selectedChapter].levels[selectedLevel].blocks"></block>

</section>
```

Here is my controller :

```
app.controller(
  'gameCtrl',
  [
    '$scope', '$rootScope', '$document', 'localStorage',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $document, localStorage)
    {
      $scope.newMove = function()
      {
        $scope.movesNumber ++;
      };
    }
  ]
);
```

Here is my directive :

```
app.directive(
  'block',
  [
    "$rootScope", "$document",
    function($rootScope, $document)
    {
      function link(scope, element, attributes)
      {
        if(scope.block.isDroppable)
        {
          $document.on('blockDropped', checkDroppedElement);
        }

        function checkDroppedElement(event)
        {
          scope.$parent.newMove();
        }
      }

      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '{{ block.value }}',
        link:     link
      };
    }
  ]
);
```

Comment: You dont need to do $parent because they share the same scope

Comment: @JsIsAwesome No, there is ngRepeat also.

Comment: So what? i dont understand

Comment: ngRepeat creates new child scope.

Comment: But the newMove() its outside the ng-repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The external DOM event is out of angular $digest loop:

```
$document.on('blockDropped', checkDroppedElement);
```

You need to manually $apply:

```
function checkDroppedElement(event) {
      scope.$parent.$apply(function () {
          scope.$parent.newMove();
      });
}
```